# Extract exact words in a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, formula, vba

Trying to separate data in cell **a** to cell **b**.

I have about 38,000 lines and in those lines I have data that I need extracted out of the description such as size, color, fit etc.

Below is an example.

```
Shirt color: blue size: xl
Shirt BLACK
Shirt - Black
```

Or any combination of data.

I would like on the lines that have size: xl color: blue to be extracted and put into b c d e column.

Same with just the `-Black xl` would like those extracted and put in a separate row.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This is not a free code-writing service but exists to help others with code or functions they are trying to develop.  As such, we expect to see clear cut questions with examples of data, attempted code, actual output, desired output, research efforts to solve the problem, etc.  Please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); and also [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4):

First create a simple *UDF()* to extract a color-word from a phrase:

```
Public Function GetColor(inpt As String) As String
   ary = Array("red", "green", "blue", "white", "black", "gray", "grey", "yellow")
   GetColor = ""

   For Each a In ary
      If InStr(1, LCase(inpt), a) > 0 Then
         GetColor = a
         Exit Function
      End If
   Next a
End Function
```

and apply it to a column:

[image]

You would naturally modify this sample *UDF()* to include your set of color-words.  You would then create and use similar *UDF()s* to extract sizes, article types, etc.

**EDIT#1:**

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=GetColor(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**